# Data transfer from one to project to another in a Solution

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, delegates

I have a C# solution with multiple projects in it.

There is one project called **Console** which run as a service and this project has a reference to the **hostSoftware** project (**hostSoftware** doesn't have a reference to **Console**, obviously).

I want to transfer a `bool` value from **Console** to **hostSoftware**.

**Console**: Checks the license and I want to send the `bool` value to **hostSoftware** for further checks.

```cs
var StatusParameters1 = new StatusParameters();
{
    StatusParameters1.Name = "Log";
    int returnCode = 0;
    bool logStatus = LHandler.GetLogStatus(out LogStatus);
    var status = LHandler.ReadLFile(out returnCode);
    if (logStatus)
    {
        if (status.SoftLisenceInfoList[0].SoftId2 == Constants.SoftwareId2)
        {
            StatusParameters1.Value = LogStatus;
        }
        else 
        {
            StatusParameters1.Value = false;
        }
```

**hostSoftware**: I want `StatusParameters1.Value` in my host project `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file.

Note: I tried to use a delegate but got this error:

> No matching constructor found on type MainWindow

Is there any other approach?

**EDIT:**
I just discovered that there is another project called `ServerService` which communicated with Console Project and `hostSoftware` is communicating with `ServerService` so the data flow is : `Console` -> `ServerService` -> `hostSoftware`.

`ServerService` is a service which is being used as `Service References` in `hostSoftware`

Comment: Be aware that constructing a _new_ `MainWindow` won't help you anyway because it won't be the same `MainWindow` that you already have open.

Comment: yes, thanks! then what approach would be legal to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like `hostSoftware` calls to `Console` (through HTTP or something) - is that correct?

Comment: [Full Duplex Named Pipes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1179195/Full-Duplex-Asynchronous-Read-Write-with-Named-Pip) | [Inter Process Com](https://csharpvault.com/inter-process-communication/) | [WCF Comparison with Web Services and Remoting](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45698/WCF-Comparison-with-Web-Services-and-NET-Remoting) | [Socket](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/socket-programming-in-C-Sharp/) | [Socket](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-c-sharp/) | [Client-server](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12286/Simple-Client-server-Interactions-using-C)

Comment: @Llama no, it is communicating over threads

Comment: There are not enough details to answer the question usefully. Everything depends on how the `Console` project code is invoked and its relationship to the `hostSoftware` project, and _none_ of those details are present here. Please fix the question so it includes a [mcve] that shows exactly how the two projects relate to each other, and explain what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Don't use comments to provide clarification. [**Edit your post**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67782658/edit)

Answer (score -1):

I can understand that you want your service to verify the client, and then the client can call your service. If so, you can refer to [Extending WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/), You can choose a suitable way to add security verification to your service.

Comment: The question is poorly written, but based on the author's comments above and the literal reading of the question, it seems clear enough that while the code is in different projects, it is still within the same _process_. WCF or other interprocess communication APIs would not be appropriate here.